# Проблема настройки slick слайдера

Tags: javascript

Верстаю под Bootstrap. Есть слайдер http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. С горем пополам настроил слайдер таким образом, что при ширине окна браузера <991 px слайдер исчезает и его контент отображается блочно, но при увеличении ширины браузера слайдер не появляется. Собственно нужно, чтобы при расширении окна браузера >991px слайдер вновь появлялся.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        responsive: [
                     {
                     breakpoint: 991,
                     settings: "unslick",   
                     }
                    ]
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой код, совсем не обязательно определять ширину устройства с помощью плагина слайдера, да и после того как он выключается, код скорее всего уже перестаёт работать:

```
function slideDetect() {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 992 && !destroy) {             
       $('.slider').slick('unslick');
       destroy = true;
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 991 && destroy) {
       $('.slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        slidesToShow: 2,
      });

      destroy = false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var destroy = true; // UPD. Ошибочно было false, спасибо Makarenko_I_V

    slideDetect();

    $(window).resize(function() {
       slideDetect()
    });
});
```

Comment: К сожалению, этот код не работает.

Comment: @Pheel код работает, @MasterAlex допустил небольшую ошибку, `var destroy = true;` должен быть изначально `true` и инициализирован в самом начале JavaScript-а.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, точно, спасибо за поправку, сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.js-slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick('resize');
});

$(window).on('orientationchange', function () {
    $('.js-slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick('resize');
});
```